# How to upload file contents into variable Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, file, variables, file-upload

I'm making a script that uploads a script, or "payload" to a site with these steps:

```
1. User enters URL with * in place of query
2. User selects payload, which is simply a file with a pre-written JS script.
3. The * is replaced with the contents of the payload.
4. The URL with a script replacing the query is opened in an iframe.
```

How would I do this? My main problem is the file-uploading-into-variable part. Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

  </head>

  <body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

    <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
    <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
    <h4>Please report all issues to <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
    <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
    <br />

    <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
    <h5>Example: https://www.google.com/#q=*</h5>
    <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

    <h4>Select a payload:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="myPayload" placeholder="Enter payload path"> <button onclick="selectPayload()">Submit</button>


    <script>

      function myFunction() {

        var errors = [];
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

        if ( !x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://") ) {

          errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS in URL');

        }

        if (!x.includes("*")) {

          errors.push('missing * in place of query')

        }

        // Renders errors
        if (errors.length) {

           x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!'; 

        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

        }

      function selectPayload() {



      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

How would I let the user browse through files and then select one 
and upload it to a variable?

Comment: Which files are you referencing? What is being uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the `type` attribute of your `input` tag to be `"file"`, e.g.:

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

Then create a filereader:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
```

Since the file will be read asynchronously, you should add a callback to proceed further, e.g. something like:

```
fr.onload = function(){... do something ...};
```

To read the file call `readAsText` (for example, add this to an `onclick` event):

```
fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
```

Once the file has been loaded the content will be a string in `fr.result`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) has more documentation and examples.

Comment: This is kind of vague... Could you go into more detail?

Comment: Which parts are vague/where do you want more detail?

Comment: Maybe just add a full block of code putting all the parts together.