# How to put a file in my data and posted with javascript

Tags: javascript

pleas
I have my following code:

```js
let data = {
    input: {
      amount: 100,
      identity_card: document.forms["form"]["file"].files[0],
    }
}
```

But it does not work.
I would like my identity_card attribute to be a file.
I tried every possible way, but without success.
I even tried with the FormData but without success

Comment: Worth reading up on: [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). And some related questions: [How to upload file contents into variable Javascript/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43669894/1650337), [How to assign file contents into a Javascript var](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3875833/1650337)

Answer (score 0):

To upload files, you need to use `multipart/form-data` encoding.
Please read more about file upload [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications).
You can however save your images as Object Urls and submit using `application/json` encoding